# How to convert a txt file from UTF-8 to UTF-16?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, utf-16

Is there any scripts (batch script or ruby) to change a txt file encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-16?

The codes likes below

require 'iconv'

$RegisterMark=[174].pack('U*')

puts '--------------------'

puts "$RegisterMark Vaule:"

puts $RegisterMark

puts $RegisterMark.encoding

$utf16RegisterMark = Iconv.conv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $RegisterMark )

puts '--------------------'

puts "$utf16RegisterMark Vaule:"

puts $utf16RegisterMark

puts $utf16RegisterMark.encoding

file = File.new("C:/Output.txt","w")

file.puts $utf16RegisterMark

file.close

//////////////////////////////

Question:

1. Why $utf16RegisterMark.encoding is ASCII-8BIT not UTF-16?
2. Open output.txt with notepad, check the encoding is "Unicode Big endian", how can let its encoding Unicode (Unicode litte endian)
   ?

Comment: Umm... UTF-8 **is** Unicode, of course.

Comment: Loosely, Unicode gives a number (called a codepoint) for each character. How do you store this number is called an encoding and UTF-8 is such. So your question has no meaning, sorry.

Comment: Notepad support ANSI, Unicode, Unicode big endian, UTF-8, so the Unicode is UTF-16

Comment: Then UTF-16 is UTF-16 and UTF-8 is UTF-8 and both are Unicode. You should update your question to what you really mean.

Comment: In this case, when Notepad says "Unicode", it means "UTF-16". Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 are Unicode encodings. Blame Notepad for poor use of terminology.

Comment: Sorry, the tile can't be edited

Answer (score 1):

```
def f x
  x
end
```

***Update:***

Ok, the original question didn't mention UTF-16 but just said "How to convert UTF-8 to Unicode?". So, darn it, now I have to think and update with a real answer...

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'iconv'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Iconv.conv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', 'How now brown cow')
=> "\376\377\000H\000o\000w\000 \000n\000o\000w\000 \000b\000r\000o\000w\000n\000 \000c\000o\000w"
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, UTF-8 is a form of Unicode.